# Proble with installing psychopy - error: command 'swig.exe' failed or cannot connect to None

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, psychopy

I try to install psychopy and constantly getting some errors.
While trying to install it via pip or pycharm I get this:

```
    running build_ext
    building 'pyWinhook._cpyHook' extension
    swigging pyWinhook/cpyHook.i to pyWinhook/cpyHook_wrap.c
    swig.exe -python -o pyWinhook/cpyHook_wrap.c pyWinhook/cpyHook.i
    error: command 'swig.exe' failed: No such file or directory
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\exemed\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\exemed\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3gqy6ttx\\pywinhook_dfa44b41fdb7490dbae3492c6c94362e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\exemed\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3gqy6ttx\\pywinhook_dfa44b41fdb7490dbae3492c6c94362e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\exemed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bscln1ih\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\exemed\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\venv\include\site\python3.6\pyWinhook'
```

And when I tried to do this in Google Colab this happened:

```
NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"
```

Looking for a fix for any of these environments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=error%3A+command+%27swig.exe%27+failed%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/files/swigwin/